Poincaré dual for the hyperplane class $[H] \in H_{2n-2}(\Bbb CP^n,\Bbb Z)$
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. If we denote $\mathcal{O}(1) \to \Bbb C P^n$ the dual of the tautological line bundle we have that $$c_1(\mathcal{O}(1)) = [\omega_{FS}],$$ where $\omega_{FS}$ is the Fubini-Study form on $\Bbb CP^n$. Now there seems to be a dual way of thinking about this which has something to do with hyperplanes in $\Bbb CP^n$. I am not really familiar with these things, but I think (correct me if I'm wrong) its a result of Poincaré duality.
If I understand this correctly a hyperplane $H$ in $\Bbb CP^1$ is codimension $1$-linear subspace given by $$a_0z_0+\dots+a_nz_n=0$$ where $[z_0,\dots,z_n]$ are the homogeneous coordinates. Now supposedly there is a canonical hyperplane obtained simply by $H$ being $z_n = 0$. This then gives a fundamental class $[H] \in H_{2n-2}(\Bbb CP^n,\Bbb Z)$ and all other hyperplanes are homologous to $H$ via an action of $\mathrm{PGL}(n+1,\Bbb C)$.
The question I'm after is that is the Poincaré dual of $[H]$ then given by $[\omega_{FS}]$? If so, how is this concluded?
Its probably worth mentioning here that I know that if $L$ is a line bundle over $X$ such that $L = \mathcal{O}(D)$ for some divisor of $X$, then $$c_1(L) = \eta_D$$ where $\eta_D$ is the Poincaré dual of the fundamental class of the divisor $D$.  Using this the question would reduce to showing that $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is given by some divisor on $\Bbb CP^n$. My hunch is that we can choose any hyperplane  $H$ on $\Bbb CP^n$ and $\mathcal{O}(1)$ would then be given by $\mathcal{O}(H)$, but I don't know how to verify this. It seems that $\mathcal{O}(1)$ should then depend on the chosen hyperplane/divisor.
